# How do I shift and repeat the same function in MATLAB and then sum the total overlapping area under those curves?

Tags: matlab, convolution

I have a function which is similar to this

```
x=-10:0.1:10;
   y=sqrt((36-x.^2)/9);
   plot(x,y)
```

I would like to shift it by 1 and repeat this 20 times (so that I have as many repeats as values of x). I tried with things like circshift and this:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5] 
B=zeros(size(A));
n=1; %Shift units
B(n+1:end)=A(1:end-n)
```

but I'm stuck. Once I have that, I'd like to calculate the sum of all the overlapping areas in a certain range (say -10:0). But that is even further away from my skills... any tip is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by " shift it by 1 and repeat"  Do you want the first iteration to be `x = -10:0.1:10` & then the next to be `x=-9:0.1:11` and so on?  ... or would the second iteration be `x=-9.9:.1:10.1` ?

Comment: Also in your example y is a complex number.  So plotting will throw a warning and only plot the real component.

Comment: thanks, I'd like the total range to remain fixed (-10:0.1:10). But one function will start at -10, the next at -9 etc, even if they get 'chopped' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is plot all 200 lines at once each line shifted by 1 element equivalent to `0.1` in your example

```
spacing = 0.1;
x = [-10:spacing:10]';                       %Size 1 x 201
shift = 0:spacing:spacing*numel(x)-spacing;  %Size 201 x 1

%As long as you have a relatively new version of Matlab this will expand into a matrix
x = x + shift;              %Size 201x201
y = sqrt((36-x.^2)/9); %Size 201x201

plot(x,y);  %This will plot all 201 lines at once.
```

Note your equations gives complex numbers for y when `x^2` is greater than 36.  So the plot will only contain the real elements of y